# ArrayAdapter<String> filter only matches from the beginning of a word

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` backed by an `ArrayAdapter<String>`. Contents such as:

- 309
- C309
- A 309
- A C309
- A 309N

If I perform: `....getFilter().filter("309")` on my adapter the result is:

- 309
- A 309
- A 309N

Basically only content where there is a match at the beginning of a new string is returned. Just wondering is this working as expected as I want to return all strings for which there is a substring match?

Thanks in advance, Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, this is the expected behaviour (as far as i can tell).
on line 483 of [ArrayAdapter.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L483) you find this: `if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {`
it then splits the string into words and does startsWith() on each of them.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the String method `startsWith()`.  Here is the Javadoc page for it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)

edit: So in context of your ArrayAdapter you would just have to loop through each value and check there's a match with the `startsWith()` method.

Comment: I'm using the `Filter` returned by the `ArrayAdapter` to automatically perform the filter. The question that I'm basically asking is whether this is the default behaviour for the filter which will then require me to implement a custom one.